# CXF generates WSDL where Fault extends tns:exception

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, java2wsdl

I have a CXF Fault class defined that way:

```
@WebFault(name = "FaultContainer",
        faultBean = "myapi.transport.FaultContainer",
        targetNamespace = "mynmspace")
public class ServiceFaultSecond extends java.lang.Exception {
...
}
```

As you can see, it extends normal java Exception. The problem is, that in WSDL generated by CXF this class is represented that way:

```
<xs:complexType name="serviceFaultSecond">
 <xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="tns:exception">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="faultInfo" type="tns:FaultContainer"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here it extends a "tns:exception" (that than extends tns:throwable). Now, when I try to generate a Client, there are compile errors - it expects mynmspace.Exception and mynmspace.Throwable instead of java.lang...

Normally CXF does not put xs:extension element into WSDL, why it happens now?

Comment: Same here, not an isolated problem... using 2.7.3 of cxf